# jQuery UI: Set slider scrollbar's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using jQuery UI's slider scrollbar and I would like to position it when the page loads. I'm using the [sample code from example](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll), but I've never worked with jQuery UI before, so I don't know what I need to change. The position of slider should be under some value (in example are 20 values) and the value should be visible.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply specify the [`value`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value) when you initialise the slider:

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() 
{
    $( "#slider" ).slider(
    {
        min : 0,
        max: 10,
        value : 5 
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKAth/)

**Update**

JS:

```
$(function() 
{
    //scrollpane parts
    var scrollPane = $( ".scroll-pane" ),
    scrollContent = $( ".scroll-content" );

    //build slider
    var initialValue = 75; // 0 - 99 

    var scrollbar = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider(
    {
        value : initialValue,
        slide: function( event, ui ) 
        {
            if ( scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width() ) 
            {
                scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
                    ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
                ) + "px" );
            } 
            else 
            {
                scrollContent.css( "margin-left", 0 );
            }
        }
    });

    // Update offset position based on initialValue
    scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
        initialValue / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
    ) + "px" );

    //append icon to handle
    var handleHelper = scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" )
        .mousedown(function() 
        {
            scrollbar.width( handleHelper.width() );
        })
        .mouseup(function() 
        {
            scrollbar.width( "100%" );
        })
        .append( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical'></span>" )
        .wrap( "<div class='ui-handle-helper-parent'></div>" ).parent();

    //change overflow to hidden now that slider handles the scrolling
    scrollPane.css( "overflow", "hidden" );

    //size scrollbar and handle proportionally to scroll distance
    function sizeScrollbar() 
    {
        var remainder = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
        var proportion = remainder / scrollContent.width();
        var handleSize = scrollPane.width() - ( proportion * scrollPane.width() );
        scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" ).css(
        {
            width: handleSize,
            "margin-left": -handleSize / 2
        });
        handleHelper.width( "" ).width( scrollbar.width() - handleSize );
    }

    //reset slider value based on scroll content position
    function resetValue() 
    {
        var remainder = scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width();
        var leftVal = scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) === "auto" ? 0 :
            parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) );
        var percentage = Math.round( leftVal / remainder * 100 );
        scrollbar.slider( "value", percentage );
    }

    //if the slider is 100% and window gets larger, reveal content
    function reflowContent() 
    {
        var showing = scrollContent.width() + parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 );
        var gap = scrollPane.width() - showing;
        if ( gap > 0 ) 
        {
            scrollContent.css( "margin-left", parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 ) + gap );
        }
    }

    //change handle position on window resize
    $( window ).resize(function() 
    {
        resetValue();
        sizeScrollbar();
        reflowContent();
    });
    //init scrollbar size
    setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
});
```

CSS:

```
.scroll-pane { overflow: auto; width: 99%; float:left; }
.scroll-content { width: 2440px; float: left; }
.scroll-content-item { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; font-size: 3em; line-height: 96px; text-align: center; }
.scroll-bar-wrap { clear: left; padding: 0 4px 0 2px; margin: 0 -1px -1px -1px; }
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider { background: none; border:0; height: 2em; margin: 0 auto;  }
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-handle-helper-parent { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle { top:.2em; height: 1.5em; }
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle .ui-icon { margin: -8px auto 0; position: relative; top: 50%; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-pane ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <div class="scroll-content">
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">1</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">2</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">3</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">4</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">5</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">6</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">7</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">8</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">9</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">10</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">11</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">12</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">13</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">14</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">15</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">16</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">17</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">18</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">19</div>
        <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">20</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pFwFj/

Comment: Your example doesn't work with this one http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll. Value just changes position of slider, but not position of content. Value also depends on width of browser.

Comment: See updated answer... The bits to look for are the bits I added (`initialValue`)

Comment: Yes, that's what I want :) Is it possible to keep position on browser's width change?

Answer (score 0):

Just put as many elements as you like in your HTML and adjust the width of the slider in CSS.

In this example you see the original slider with 20 items:
http://jsfiddle.net/fN2v5/1/

In this example I took out 10 items:
http://jsfiddle.net/fN2v5/2/

I divided the former width by 2 and got 1220px for 10 items.

```
.scroll-content { width: 1220px; float: left; }
```

And I used only 10 of the former 20 elements in HTML.

```
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">1</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">2</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">3</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">4</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">5</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">6</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">7</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">8</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">9</div>
<div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header">10</div>
```

Comment: The OP is talking about a jQuery slider... Where you setting the scrollbar position?

Comment: The OP wants to set the scrollbar position to a given place when it first loads.